# Return response with errors in MediatR pipeline behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mediatr

I'm new to MediatR, trying to make request validation using pipeline behavior, all the examples that I came across were throwing ValidationException if any errors happening.
below code is an example of validation pipeline:

```
public class ValidationPipeline<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator> _validators;

    public ValidationPipeline(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)
    {
        _validators = validators;
    }

    public Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext<TRequest>(request);
        var validationFailures = _validators
            .Select(validator => validator.Validate(context))
            .SelectMany(validationResult => validationResult.Errors)
            .Where(validationFailure => validationFailure != null)
            .ToList();

        if (validationFailures.Any())
        {
            throw new FluentValidation.ValidationException(validationFailures);
        }
        
        return next();
    }
}
```

this method works fine, but I want to return the response with validation errors (without) throwing exception,  so I tried this:

```
public class ValidationBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, BaseResponse<TResponse>>
    where TRequest : IRequest<BaseResponse<TResponse>>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator> _validators;

    public ValidationBehavior(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)
    {
        _validators = validators;
    }

    public Task<BaseResponse<TResponse>> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<BaseResponse<TResponse>> next)
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext<TRequest>(request);
        var validationFailures = _validators
            .Select(validator => validator.Validate(context))
            .SelectMany(validationResult => validationResult.Errors)
            .Where(validationFailure => validationFailure != null)
            .ToList();

        if (validationFailures.Any())
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new BaseResponse<TResponse>
            {
                Code = 400,
                Message = "Validation error",
                Error = validationFailures.Select(err => err.ErrorMessage)
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return next();
        }
    }
```

but now the validation pipeline code does not execute,
and execution go to regular handlers (ex: Register User Handler).

my response (used in all handlers):

```
public class BaseResponse<TResponse>
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public TResponse Result { get; set; }
    public object Error { get; set; }
    public string TraceIdentifier { get; set; }
}
```

register the behaviour with DI like this:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(ValidationBehavior<,>));
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you register the MediatR request handlers in the startup.cs and how you use this MediatR in asp.net core? Details about how to use it, I suggest you could refer to this [article](https://www.kiltandcode.com/2021/02/15/using-mediatr-request-handlers-in-aspnet-core-to-decouple-code/).

Comment: When you say the validation pipeline "doesn't trigger" what exactly do you mean? Can you no longer hit breakpoints anywhere in the pipeline?

Comment: pipeline code does not execute (I put breakpoint at the first line of "Handle" method)... and execution go to regular handlers (ex: Register User Handler) .

Comment: So just replacing the code that throws the exception with the code that returns a `BaseResponse<TResponse>` causes the entire `Handle` method to never execute? That doesn't sound right, obviously. You're sure you're not swallowing/ignoring some unhandled exception that may be happening there?

Comment: Does your handler accept a [message](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki#requestresponse) of type `IRequest<BaseResponse<TResponse>>`? If not, then this pipeline behaviour will not execute.

Comment: have you been able to solve? I have the same error

Answer (score 4):

It's doesn't trigger because this pipeline doesn't match your IRequest anymore.
In your case **TResponse** is already **BaseResponse<>** and you wrapping it once more.

I assume you have the following request structure:

```
public record TestDto(string Result);

public class TestCommand(int Id, string Name) : IRequest<BaseResponse<TestDto>>;

public class TestCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<TestCommand, BaseResponse<TestDto>>
{
    public async Task<BaseResponse<TestDto>> Handle(TestCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In this case **TResponse** is **BaseResponse<TestDto>**.

To solve the problem you can do the following:

Add a constructor with parameters to your BaseResponse<T> like this:

```
public class BaseResponse<TResponse>
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public TResponse Result { get; set; }
    public object Error { get; set; }
    public string TraceIdentifier { get; set; }

    public BaseResponse()
    {

    }

    public BaseResponse(int code, string message, object error)
    {
        Code = code;
        Message = message;
        Error = error;
    }
}
```

Then if validation fails you have to create this object. You might use Activator to achieve this.

```
public class ValidationPipeline<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator> _validators;

    public ValidationPipeline(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)
    {
        _validators = validators;
    }

    public Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext<TRequest>(request);
        var validationFailures = _validators
            .Select(validator => validator.Validate(context))
            .SelectMany(validationResult => validationResult.Errors)
            .Where(validationFailure => validationFailure != null)
            .ToList();

        if (validationFailures.Any())
        {
            var code = 400;
            var message = "Validation error";
            var error = validationFailures.Select(err => err.ErrorMessage);

            return (TResponse)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TResponse),
                                                       code, 
                                                       message, 
                                                       error);
        }
        
        return next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used next method. First of all I'm using [Adrdalis.Result](https://github.com/ardalis/Result) or via nuget [Ardalist.Result](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ardalis.Result) i find it very usefull.
Pipeline code:

```
public class FluentValidationPipelineBehaviour<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> _validators;

    public FluentValidationPipelineBehaviour(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)
    {
        _validators = validators;
    }
    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        var requestType = request.GetType();
        if (requestType != null)
        {
            var attribute = requestType.GetCustomAttribute<FluentValidationAttribute>();
            if (attribute != null && attribute.IsEnabled)
            {
                var context = new ValidationContext<TRequest>(request);
                var validationResults = await Task.WhenAll(
                    _validators.Select(v =>
                        v.ValidateAsync(context, cancellationToken)));

                var failures = validationResults
                    .Where(r => r.Errors.Any())
                    .SelectMany(r => r.Errors)
                    .ToList();
            
                if (failures.Any())
                {
                    if (attribute.ThrowExceptionOnError)
                    {
                        throw new ValidationException(failures);
                    }
                    return GetValidatableResult(failures.AsErrors());
                }
            }
        }
        return await next();
    }

    private static TResponse GetValidatableResult(List<ValidationError> validationErrors)
    {
#pragma warning disable CS8603
#pragma warning disable CS8602
#pragma warning disable CS8600
        return (TResponse)(typeof(Result<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TResponse).GetGenericArguments())
            .GetMethod("Invalid").Invoke(null, new object?[] { validationErrors }));
#pragma warning restore CS8600
#pragma warning restore CS8602
#pragma warning restore CS8603
    }
}
```

I'm using FluentValidationAttribute to configure fluentvalidation behaviour

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class FluentValidationAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; } = true;
    public bool ThrowExceptionOnError { get; set; } = false;
}
```

Use it on Command / Query etc;